# Is there a way to have multiple lines in a single table column using xtabular?

Tags: xtab

I cannot get a new line within the same column using `\newline` in `xtabular`, whereas it works in the case of `tabular`. Is there another option in `xtabular` environment? Search did not produce any relevant results.

Comment: Please post a small, compilable document demonstrating the problem. Also, if you are really using a package by that name, please tell us where we can get a copy.

Comment: You want a new line in the same row or what?

Comment: We cannot guess your particular problem without a MWE, but the command `\newline` works also in `xtabular`.  Note that `\newline` has no effect en  `l`,`c` and `r` columns (in both types of environments), but do the job in columns as `p{2cm}`.

Comment: @Fran I guess your answer pointed out the root cause of the problem. I was using a c column.